# Coding techniques

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have three tables in mysql database with the name of `adduser`, `academic_record` and `admission` , all tables have same column name `std_id` `same date type`, both tables `academic_record` and `admission` is linked with foreign key the column of `std_id` on `adduser`.

Now when i delete data from adduser, i found error that cannot be add or deleted... foreign constraint add.. 
can any one give me the solution
I use this query for  foreign key

```
alter table academic_record
add foregn key constraint fk_peracademic_record
where academic_record(std_id)
references adduser(std_id);
```

Comment: You have to delete the rows on `academic_record` and `ambition` that relates to that user before you can remove the user. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905470/cannot-delete-or-update-a-parent-row-a-foreign-key-constraint-fails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that I have understood your question correctly, (you want to delete the records from the other tables when a record in the adduser tables is deleted, what you need is to add the [ON DELETE CASCADE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) option.