# JPA - ConstraintViolationException on delete

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I searched the internet, tried many methods but I still have a problem during the removal.Please give me any directions because I want to understand what I'm doing wrong.

I have several entities but in brief:

```
public class PetOwner extends User {
    private String address;
    private String telefon;

    @OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.REMOVE})
    private List<Appointment> appointments;
}


public class Appointment {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST})
    @JoinColumn(name = "owner_id")
    private PetOwner petOwner;
}
```

When i try delete the Appointment with this method(JpaRepository)

```
@Transactional
    public void delete(Appointment appointment){
        appointmentRepository.delete(appointment);
    }
```

Spring throws a exception:

```
MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

Only way is set in Appointment.class

```
@ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name = "owner_id")
    private PetOwner petOwner;
```

But then in addition to the meeting also removes PetOwner. Please for directions on how to handle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without entering in the debate about creating a hierarchy to reflect properties (not nature), you can use two approaches here.

First, you can write your relationships better. I don't know what's your JPA implementation of choice, but sometimes they mess the tables creating unnecessary linked tables. So, better safe than sorry:

On PetOwner, use:

```
@OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.REMOVE}, mappedBy="petOwner")
private List<Appointment> appointments;
```

Second approach is to make explicit your owner does not have the appointment prior the removal, so:

```
@Transactional
public void delete(Appointment appointment){
    appointment.getPetOwner().getAppointments().remove(appointment);
    appointmentRepository.delete(appointment);
}
```

This one is really bad because you can have a huge performance problem when an owner have to much appointments.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should only cascade on `@OneToMany`. Secondly the error appears to be from the DB, not from JPA. Your foreign key appears to be set up wrong.

Refer to this answer for FK: [FK restriction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905470/cannot-delete-or-update-a-parent-row-a-foreign-key-constraint-fails)

The proper way to set up what you are trying to do is :

```
 @OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.DELETE},mappedBy = "petOwner")
 private List<Appointment> appointments;
```

and

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "owner_id")
private PetOwner petOwner;
```