# dropping tables in sql

Tags: mysql

Hey so I am very new to SQL and am having trouble dropping tables, the SQL I have so far is:

```
CREATE TABLE COMPANY (
cname       VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL,
city        VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL,       
street      VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL,
bldgnum     DECIMAL(4)      NOT NULL,
email       VARCHAR(320)    NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT comp_pkey PRIMARY KEY(cname),
CONSTRAINT comp_ckey1 UNIQUE(city, street, bldgnum),
CONSTRAINT comp_ckey2 UNIQUE(email) );


CREATE TABLE DEPARTMENT (
cname       VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL,
dname       VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT dept_pkey PRIMARY KEY(cname, dname),
CONSTRAINT dept_fkey FOREIGN KEY(cname) REFERENCES COMPANY(cname) );


CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE (
enumber             VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL,
first_name          VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL,   
last_name           VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL,
date_of_brith       DATE                NULL,
salary              DECIMAL(7,2)    NOT NULL,
cname               VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL,
dname               VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL,
employee_type       VARCHAR(50)         NULL,
manager_of_cname    VARCHAR(50)         NULL,
manager_of_dname    VARCHAR(50)         NULL,

CONSTRAINT emp_pkey PRIMARY KEY(enumber),
CONSTRAINT emp_fkey FOREIGN(cname, dname) REFERENCES DEPARTMENT(cname, dname),
CONSTRAINT salary CHECK (salary < 0) );


CREATE TABLE PHONE (
pnumber         DECIMAL(10)         NOT NULL,
cname           VARCHAR(50)         NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT phn_pkey PRIMARY KEY(pnumber),
CONSTRAINT phn_fkey FOREIGN KEY(cname) REFERENCES COMPANY(cname) );
```

This has some errors in it I believe but I want to drop these tables but get an error saying: Cannot delete or update a parent row: foreign key constraint fails. This is my drop table SQL:

```
DROP TABLE COMPANY;
DROP TABLE DEPARTMENT;
DROP TABLE EMPLOYEE;
DROP TABLE PHONE;
```

Sorry for any facepalms created while reading this, and thank you for any help as it is very appreciated.

Comment: Use DROP CONSTRAINT to remove the constraints, the you can drop the tables.

Comment: also which database application are you using? you shouldn't be tagging both mysql and sql-server, you are likely using one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start with dropping the child tables. Here is the hierarcy you have:

Company --> Department --> Employee

You need to first drop the Employee table, then the Department and then the Company table. The point is that, SQL Server cannot drop a table while that table is being referenced by another table.

```
DROP TABLE EMPLOYEE;
DROP TABLE DEPARTMENT;
DROP TABLE COMPANY;
```

Answer (score 0):

On the employee table creation you missed the foreign key change this.

[Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905470/cannot-delete-or-update-a-parent-row-a-foreign-key-constraint-fails) ->> check with this link you find the solution