# codeiginiter: How to handel foreign key error when deleting data

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a problem in deleting data I wrote a function in model to delete data and it works but when foreign key constraint occur it show this error:

[image]

and I want to handle this error in the code and when this error occurs I want to show an error message: `You can't delete this data.`

Comment: delete the foreign key record and remove the master record

Comment: Please include the error in your question instead of referring with a link

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905470/cannot-delete-or-update-a-parent-row-a-foreign-key-constraint-fails)

Comment: Please do not link to your code.